# getOptionTimezones with core php

Tags: timezone

In the magento when I print the `getOptionTimezones` I get the result as follows

```
$data['timezone_array'] = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getOptionTimezones();

[timezone_array] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => Australia/Darwin
                            [label] => AUS Central Standard Time (Australia/Darwin)
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => Australia/Melbourne
                            [label] => AUS Eastern Standard Time (Australia/Melbourne)
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => Australia/Sydney
                            [label] => AUS Eastern Standard Time (Australia/Sydney)
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => Asia/Kabul
                            [label] => Afghanistan Standard Time (Asia/Kabul)
                        )
```

I want to do same in the with php functions but not finding useful code.

What I done is `$tzlist = DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::ALL);`

It outputs like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Africa/Abidjan
    [1] => Africa/Accra
    [2] => Africa/Addis_Ababa
    [3] => Africa/Algiers
    [4] => Africa/Asmara
    [5] => Africa/Bamako
    [6] => Africa/Bangui
    [7] => Africa/Banjul
    [8] => Africa/Bissau
```

How can i convert the timezone name to full name like the `label` in below array.

```
[value] => Australia/Darwin
[label] => AUS Central Standard Time (Australia/Darwin)
```

Comment: i think this is your are expect https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755704/php-timezone-list

Comment: you can place ans here and change status as accept your ans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `IntlTimeZone::getDisplayName()`, e.g.:

echo `IntlTimeZone::createTimeZone("Australia/Darwin")->getDisplayName();`

Outputs:

```
Australian Central Standard Time
```

Though many will change throughout the year for daylight saving. If you want to check for this and add the alternate daylight/summer display name you can do something like:

```
$tz = IntlTimeZone::createTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
echo $tz->getDisplayName(), "\n";
if ($tz->useDaylightTime()) {
    echo $tz->getDisplayName(true);
}
```

which outputs:

```
Pacific Standard Time
Pacific Daylight Time
```

Originally answered by [Paul Crovella](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3942918/paul-crovella) on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45521276/get-all-timezones)